# MAVEN : mvn --version Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: maven, maven-2

when i run the command "mvn --version" i get the following error.

```
mvn --version

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
```

It looks like I need to get rid of "bin/java" at the end

How do i fix this ? any suggestions?

Comment: I hope you don't use Maven 2 anymore..?

Answer (score 4):

set JAVA_HOME where your JDK's root directory is

```
export JAVA_HOME= /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51
```

Comment: I get this error if I try this command "bash: export: `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51': not a valid identifier "

Comment: I found a solution from this. Thank you.

Comment: I Can't, this is not my question. I have marked it up.